# how can i get the child in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
const navArr = [
  {
    path: "/introduction",
    title: "회사소개",
    subTitle: [{ title: "summary" }, { title: "vision" }],
  },
]

{navArr.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <NavItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleHoverToggle} className={classes.navItem}>
                {obj.title}
              </MenuItem>
            </NavItem>
          );
        })}
```

I want to access the title in subtitle. how access title in subtle. I want to insert that instead of '{obj.title}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Because `subTitle` is also an array so you would need to map it again:**

Something like this:

```
<NavItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={handleHoverToggle} className={classes.navItem}>
    {obj.subTitle.map(sub => sub.title).join(',')}
  </MenuItem>
</NavItem>;
```

Comment: Thank you! But, occur 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

Comment: Could you verify if it's `subTitle` not `title` as your OP?

Comment: oh! title in subtitle is wrong, I change title in subTitle to titleSub, and It's good! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your subTitle is an array and assuming that you want each of your title in your subTitle as a MenuItem

**Solution:**

```
const navArr = [
  {
    path: "/introduction",
    title: "회사소개",
    subTitle: [{ title: "summary" }, { title: "vision" }],
  },
]

{navArr.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <NavItem>
                {obj.subTitle.map(item=>{
                return(
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleHoverToggle} className={classes.navItem}>
                        {item.title}
                    </MenuItem>
                ) } ) }
            </NavItem>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: Thank you! but, this is wrong that title in subTitle is same title of 1 depth.
Thanks to your help, I resolve the problem!